# ASP NET Core MVC - поместить все div в один ряд

Tags: c#, html, css, bootstrap, asp.net-core

Создаю ASP NET Core MVC приложение, использую `Bootstrap` есть три элемента `div`, нужно вывести все элементы в цикле в один ряд

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var game in Model.Games)
    {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("GameSummary", game)
    }
</div>
```

Вот код самого вью `GameSummary`

```
<div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 m-1 d-sm-inline-block">
    ... тут картинки, текст и тд
</div>
```

Вроде все 3 элемента должны быть в одном ряду, но два `div` в одном ряду, а третий последний элемент попадает уже во второй ряд, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Потому что 5+5+5 != 12. Почитайте про grid систему.

Comment: @adrug да, вы правы, поправил, спасибо - буду читать про грид систему

Comment: Да и вопрос никакого отношения к `ASP` не имеет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не стремитесь, пожалуйста, в вопрос напихать абсолютно все, с чем Вы работаете. Если у Вас вопрос про отображение элементов - никому нет дела, что у Вас творится на бэке (за исключением очень редких случаев), ведь отвечающих интересует только html и css разметка, которая приводит не к тому результату, коий хотели Вы. Просто Ваш вопрос выглядит как: *"Почему вишневый йогурт красного цвета? Покупал его в Ашане, после чего хранил в холодильнике Ariston при 3°, вчера же съел его чайной ложкой из нержавейки"*